# Windows 8 format and reinstall

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8

I found a lot of similar question but never really found an answer. I bought an ASUS laptop from BestBuy and I got windows 8 on it without any windows media cd/dvd.
I would like to install Ubunutu instead of windows, but I would also like to create some kind of windows media so I can go back to it if I ever want to.
Is there any way to do this? Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS [explained it here for a Surface](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/storage-files-and-folders/create-a-recovery-drive), but this also works for other Windows 8 OEM devices:

- Step 1:  Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search.
  (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Search.)
- Step 2:  In the search box, enter recovery, and in the search results, tap or click Recovery, and then tap or click Create a recovery drive.
- Step 3:  In the User Account Control dialog box, tap or click Yes.
- Step 4:  Tap or click to select Copy the recovery partition from the PC to the recovery drive, and then, tap or click Next.
- Step 5:  Tap or click the USB drive you want to use, and then tap or click Next.
- Step 6:  Tap or click Create.

  The recovery image and necessary recovery tools will be copied to your USB drive.
- Step 7:  After the recovery tools are copied, do one of the following:

  Tap or click `Finish` if you want to keep the recovery tools on device or Tap or click `Delete the recovery partition` if you want to remove the recovery tools from the device and free up disk space. To confirm, tap or click Delete,and when removal is complete, tap or click Finish.

To restore Windows 8, boot from the USB device and follow the steps.

Comment: Thank you, I am not able to try this now, but I will try it as soon as possible. I suppose that I need a USB that is larger that 4GB? Like 8 or 16?

Comment: For me an 8 GB was enough.